# jQuery check for both scrollHeight and scrollWidth

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
if ($(".design-canvas").prop('scrollWidth') > $(".design-canvas").width() ) {

}
```

But what I want to do now is say if the scrollWidth OR height is more than the canvas height or width.

How can this be done without two if statements?

Comment: Sorry, I should have payed more attention in math. The reason my answer fails...image scrollWidth(50) scrollHeight(60) actualWidth(100) actualHeight(25)... it fails :)